# Linear Algebra Question On Augmented Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I read the book Linear Algebra by David Lay and stumbled upon a paragraph on page $40$ that read:

> If an augmented matrix [A **b**] has a pivot position in every row, then the equation Ax = **b** may or may **not** be consistent.

I can't seem to provide myself with an example for each case, and would appreciate any help. Thanks WY.

**Note:** There is a similar question that has been posted here but it is really not the same as this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consistent:
$$
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc|c}
\color{blue}{\boxed{\color{black}{1}}} & 0 \;&\;\; 0 \\
0 & \color{blue}{\boxed{\color{black}{1}}} \;&\;\; 0
\end{array} 
\right]
$$

Inconsistent:
$$
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc|c}
\color{blue}{\boxed{\color{black}{1}}} & 0 \;&\; 0 \\
0 & 0 \;&\;\; \color{blue}{\boxed{\color{black}{1}}}
\end{array} 
\right]
$$